# Why is the domain for sec trig subs the regions where the signs are the same? Work check

Tags: calculus

I am reading my textbook and I see this:

[image]

So why are we allowed to just restrict the domain like this? I can see that we're trying to make it so that $a|\tan(\theta)| = a\tan(\theta)$ but why are we allowed to do this?

Here's a problem I am trying to solve:

$$\int \frac{\sqrt{x^2 - 4}}{x}$$ and $x = 2\sec{\theta}$

I have the answer, but why can't this domain include $\pi/2$ to $\pi$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason to make this restriction is so that there is a unique $\theta$ such that $x = a \sec \theta$. Effectively, we want an inverse function of $\sec$, but (like all trig functions) $\sec$ is not one-to-one, so we must restrict the domain of $\sec$ to make it one-to-one.  Notice that the range of $\sec$ consists of two disconnected pieces: the positives $[1, \infty)$ and the negatives $(-\infty, -1]$.  It is natural to choose $0 \le \theta < \pi/2$ to get the positive values of $\sec$, but for the negative values there are two reasonable choices: $\pi/2 < \theta \le \pi$ or $\pi < \theta \le 3\pi/2$. (Notice there is a discontinuity of $\sec$ at $\pi/2$ so either way we do not get a connected interval.) For this problem, we choose the second one because $|\tan \theta| = \tan\theta$ is a convenient property for this problem.

You can also do the problem with the other choice, but then you end up with a sign factor $|\tan \theta|/\tan\theta$ in the integral which you have to resolve by splitting into two cases.

Answer (score 0):

The book solution is glossing over an important point--the function $1/\sqrt{x^2-a^2}$, and thus its antiderivative, is only defined on the set $(-\infty,-a)\cup(a,\infty)$, which is not a connected set. So to find an antiderivative properly, each connected component (in this case $(-\infty,-a)$ and $(a,\infty)$) should be handled separately.

It just so happens that the change of variables $x\rightarrow a\sec\theta$ is helpful for both connected components. For $(a,\infty)$, this either maps to $(0,\pi/2)$ or $(\pi/2,\pi)$, while for $(-a,-\infty)$, this maps to either $(\pi,3\pi/2)$ or $(3\pi/2,2\pi)$. For each component, either choice is valid, but you have to make one or the other, because otherwise the mapping isn't unique. The book merely chooses $(0,\pi/2)$ for $(a,\infty)$ and $(\pi,3\pi/2)$ for $(-a,-\infty)$ because it makes the algebra simpler.

In fact, because it's sloppy in handling the connected components, the book actually has an error. The general form of the function that satisfies $f'(x) = 1/\sqrt{x^2-a^2}$ is
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}\ln\left|x+\sqrt{x^2-a^2}\right| + C_1 & x < -a\\\ln\left|x+\sqrt{x^2-a^2}\right|+ C_2 & x > a\end{cases}.
$$
Because the domain isn't connected, there's no continuity requirement across the gap, so the two regions can have different constants of integration.